# Two divs side by side, but first with width auto stetch , second depended on context

Tags: html, css-tables, tablecell

I need two divs side by side. But second (right) has width depended on context. And the first has to be stretched.

**[jsFiddle EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/nmz92o1r/)**

**HTML :**

```
<div class="div-table">
    <div class="div-table-row">
        <div class="div-table-col1">1st Column<br>1st Column</div>
        <div class="div-table-col2">2nd Column</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div-table      {display:table; width: 100%;}
.div-table-row  {display:table-row;  background-color : lightgray;}
.div-table-col1 {display:table-cell; width: auto; padding: 5px; background-color : green;}
.div-table-col2 {display:table-cell; width: auto; padding: 5px; background-color : orange;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `col1` a width of 100% and `col2` a width of 0%

```css
.div-table      {display:table; width: 100%;}
.div-table-row  {display:table-row;  background-color : lightgray;}
.div-table-col1 {display:table-cell; width: 100%; padding: 5px; background-color : green;}
.div-table-col2 {display:table-cell; width: 0%; padding: 5px; background-color : orange;}
```

```html
<div class="div-table">
    <div class="div-table-row">
        <div class="div-table-col1">1st Column<br>1st Column</div>
        <div class="div-table-col2">2nd Column</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And this is canonical right answer ? What about browsers compatibility ?

Comment: @Patrik This is how you size cells and it works in all major browsers

Comment: Thank you, I found this solution before I post this question. But it seems so bad solution to me... Make something 100%, and ther 0$... and thay are absolutly not... :-D

Comment: @Patrik Agree, though this is how cells work, and you should interpret it as _the 100% means it should take 100% of the available space not occupied by content, which is needed if the 0% one is empty_

Comment: OK, but now I have problem with margin-left on the second div :O 
http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/nmz92o1r/2/

Comment: @Patrik Margins doesn't work on cells, only padding. The most common,and best cross browser, way to deal with this is to add an extra cell in-between, and give it a fixed width. Another option is to set a left border on the right cell, with a fixed width acting as a margin, its downside is of course if you need it as a border, then it won't look good

Answer (score 1):

```css
.div-table     {display:table; width: 100%;}
.div-table-row {display:table-row;  background-color : lightgray;}
.div-table-col1 {display:table-cell; width: 100%; padding: 5px; background-color : green;}
.div-table-col2 {width: auto; padding: 5px; background-color : orange;}
```

```html
<div class="div-table">
    <div class="div-table-row">
        <div class="div-table-col1">1st Column<br>1st Column</div>
        <div class="div-table-col2">2nd Column</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but... But you changed display type of the second DIV... And the fist has content aligned to the bottom... The seccond is alignet to the top...  FLOAT : right is not the right and clean solution.

Comment: @Patrik as you said, float is not clean solution because of this I removed it.